# Remove Advanced Search link and Image preview from search results web part page

Tags: 2013, search, search-results, enterprise-search, sharepoint-search

How do I configure the search results webpart as follows:

1. Set your preferred search language text.
2. Search Thumbnail preview
3. Remove the Alert Me, Preferences and Advanced Search link

Answer (score 2):

1. I don't think you can force a Search Language, I believe it defaults to the server language unless you deploy SharePoint language packs.
2. Not clear on what you want with Thubnails. Tey are based on the display templates. If you want to remove them you can change the Display Templates.
3. Edit the Search Results Web Part and Uncheck:Show AlertMe link, Show Advanced Link, Show Preference link.

Comment: Thanks, in search results i want to remove Hover Panel  appears when i select a search item

Comment: Sure, you have to change the behavior of the Display Template for the item. There is no "switch" to turn it off.